# 2022 Potential Moderator Election: Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, election

It's time for us to consider holding the first election for moderators for Mythology & Folklore.

Since one moderator has expressed the desire to resigned (HDE 226868), we will be holding an election for another moderator.

So: we should hold a new election to get ourselves back up to a more regularly-available and active moderation team. To avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient number of candidates, though, I'm posting this to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves, when the actual election's nomination period starts.

Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election.

NOTE: This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up.

Currently, February 28th is the tentative date for such an election, starting with nominations, but only if we can get enough people willing to run for moderator positions.

Answer (score 4):

I would be interested in standing.

I have been a member of this site from day one, having posted a few of the example questions on the Area51 startup.

Although putting myself forward upon [leaving private beta](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/175/53)  I haven't stood since.